# How to inject dependency in Azure data factory(ADF) custom activity?

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, class-library, azure-data-factory

I am creating a custom activity by implementing IDotNetActivity Interface.

Here are the few steps that i am doing in my custom activity:

1. Read file from blob container.
2. Do some transformation
3. Override the same file.

Type of project is class library within asp.net core template. As of now I am initializing all the dependencies in my custom activity class but I want to use dependency injection to make it loosely coupled, testable and reuse some of the code which I have already written for reading files from blob container etc.

Has anyone implemented DI in .Net core class library project with inbuilt DI capability of .Net Core? If yes then please share some link so that i can also implement the same in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the ADF custom activity only supports .NET Framework class library.

On a side note, regarding to how to do DI in .net core, there's sample below

https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/dependency-injection/sample

Comment: Thanks for reply I have implemented DI in .net core API projects but never in class library projects so looking for some suggestions on that.

Comment: I think I need to install Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection as my project is of type class library and I won't have startup class which has configure services method for registering dependencies.

I am still not sure if Custom Activity will allow me to inject dependency through constructor as I have read some where that AzureBatchLinkedService works on parameter-less constructor only.